# Wp List table short data sanitizatio error

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-injection, sanitization

**This is really not sanitized:**

How to sanitize it?

Here is my full class which i have tried, but WordPress team still said its not properly sanitized.

And ## Unsafe SQL calls

When making database calls, it's highly important to protect your code from SQL injection vulnerabilities. You need to update your code to use wpdb calls and prepare() with your queries to protect them.

```
`$orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'country';`



`$order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc';`




class dsvatcalculator_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
function __construct()
{
global $status, $page;
parent::__construct(array(
'singular' => 'vat',
'plural'   => 'vats',
));
}
function column_default($item, $column_name)
{
return $item[$column_name];
}
function column_country($item)
{
return '<em>' . $item['country'] . '</em>';
}
function column_vat($item)
{
$actions = array(
'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=vats_form&id=%s">%s</a>', htmlspecialchars(absint($item['id'])), __('Edit', 'ds-vat-calculator')),
'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>',htmlspecialchars( $_REQUEST['page']),  htmlspecialchars(absint($item['id'])), __('Delete', 'ds-vat-calculator')),
);
return sprintf('%s %s',
esc_html($item['vat']),
$this->row_actions($actions)
);
}
function column_cb($item)
{
return sprintf(
'<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />',
absint($item['id'])
);
}
function get_columns()
{
$columns = array(
'cb' => esc_html('<input type="checkbox" />'),
'vat'      => esc_html(__('VAT Rate', 'ds-vat-calculator')),
'country'  => esc_html(__('Country Name', 'ds-vat-calculator')),
);
return $columns;
}
function get_sortable_columns()
{
$sortable_columns = array(
'vat'      => array('vat', true),
'country'  => array('country', true),
);
return $sortable_columns;
}
function get_bulk_actions()
{
$actions = array(
'delete' => 'Delete'
);
return $actions;
}
function process_bulk_action()
{
global $wpdb;
$dsvatcalculator_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'dsvatcalculator_vat_calculator';
if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
$idsvatcalculator = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? (array) $_REQUEST['id'] : array();
$idsvatcalculator = array_map( 'esc_attr', $idsvatcalculator );;
if (is_array($idsvatcalculator)) $idsvatcalculator = implode(',', $idsvatcalculator);
if (!empty($idsvatcalculator)) {
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $dsvatcalculator_tbl WHERE id IN($idsvatcalculator)");
}
}
}
function prepare_items()
{
global $wpdb;
$dsvatcalculator_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . 'dsvatcalculator_vat_calculator';
$per_page = 10;
$columns = $this->get_columns();
$hidden = array();
$sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
$this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
$this->process_bulk_action();
$total_items = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $dsvatcalculator_tbl");
$paged = isset($_REQUEST['paged']) ? max(0, intval($_REQUEST['paged']) - 1) : 0;
$orderby = (isset($_REQUEST['orderby']) && in_array($_REQUEST['orderby'], array_keys($this->get_sortable_columns()))) ? $_REQUEST['orderby'] : 'country';
$order = (isset($_REQUEST['order']) && in_array($_REQUEST['order'], array('asc', 'desc'))) ? $_REQUEST['order'] : 'asc';
$orderby = sanitize_sql_orderby($orderby);
$order = sanitize_sql_orderby($order);
$this->items = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $dsvatcalculator_tbl ORDER BY $orderby  $order LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", $per_page, $paged), ARRAY_A);
$this->set_pagination_args(array(
'total_items' => $total_items,
'per_page' => $per_page,
'total_pages' => ceil($total_items / $per_page)
));
}
}
```

I have tried like

`your text`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dynamic parts of your query are the column name for the order by clause, and the order direction (ASC or DESC).

I see you have code that limits the column name to the keys of your sortable columns (which are defined in a fixed array in your code), or else if the column is not in that set of keys, default to 'country'. Likewise the direction must be either 'ASC' or 'DESC' or else default to 'ASC'.

What you're doing is the proper way to sanitize column identifiers and keywords. Neither of these can be made into query parameters in SQL. They must be fixed in the query string before the query is passed to `prepare()`.

However, I don't know what your function `sanitize_sql_orderby()` does, because you didn't include that code. I doubt that it matters, though.

Regardless, I suspect your team is asking you to change it because they don't understand how SQL parameters work. Parameters can only be used in place of *values* in SQL expressions. Parameters cannot be used in place of SQL identifiers or keywords.

Maybe they simply see PHP variables being interpolated into an SQL query string, and they assume the PHP variables are untrusted. But in fact, you have limited those variables to literal values that you have defined in your code. I think this is sufficient protection.

If they insist that you should change your code, I would ask them to be more specific and show you what they would do differently.